# Is an object nullable by default

Tags: c#, nullable

I believe that an object (reference type) is nullable by default i.e. it can either have a value or be null. Why would I ever want to declare it as a nullable object explicitly?

Comment: So that you can guarantee that it will never be null (which for a lot of things is what you want).

Comment: Because sometimes an object must have a value for the function to execute properly?

Comment: So that you can change the default. And non-default values indicate that you actually meant it and didn't just use the default and maybe were not even aware of it.

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down. So you would declare it as nullable if you never want the object to be null/you always want it to have a value/you want to change the default...what if that's not the case? I have a scenario where it's perfectly ok for the object to be null, and yet it's declared as nullable, which seems a bit redundant to me

Comment: For starters, you didn't even specify a language, which matters a lot.

Comment: Right, well thanks for the downvote then.

Comment: There is no such thing as  nullable reference type. Assuming you are asking about nullable value types. Sometimes you allow the thing to be null (a way to declare an optional parameter) The compiler will force you handle the case when the value is null.

Comment: You *can't* declare something as a nullable object in C#. `object?` or `Nullable<object>` will be rejected by the compiler. Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

Variables of reference type are always nullable. You cannot declare them as nullable or not nullable.

You can mark value type variables as nullable which is useful if you want them to be able to hold one more special value (null).